# How to change element color each time scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to output one item of an array each time a visitor scrolls a x amount of pixels.

At the moment I came up with this code. But I am getting stucked when I only want to output a certain item.

I would like to output each time someone scrolls 10 px another item of the array.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
  var currentArray = 0;

  function changeColor() {
    currentArray++;
    if(currentArray > 139) {
      currentArray = 0;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    console.log(array[currentArray]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Put the html and write some details.

Comment: The html I got is only a h1 and paragraph, but I would like to output a new item of the array each time someone scrolls an amount of pixels. i.e. after I scrolled 10 px it will output array[0] and after another 10px it would output array[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

document.onscroll = function() {
  var el = parseInt(window.scrollY / 250);
  if (el <= arr.length) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent += arr[el];
    arr[el] = '';
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 200%;
}
p {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

In the above approach you output array element on each scroll, except that after every print, you clear that position in array, so you output blank string (ugly hack, but I just wanted to demonstrate you the general idea).

Change `250` in `parseInt(window.scrollY / 250)` to change the step.

I hope you will be able to apply this approach to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.scrollTop()` method:

```
if( $(document).scrollTop() > 10 ) {
    // do something
}
if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 20 ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You would have to stop perfectly at positions 20, 40, 60 and so on for this to work. Function `onscroll` is not perfect, it won't be called for every single pixel.

Comment: Yeah, I understand u @Przemek, because I tried outputting the scroll top position to the console and it skips like 10 pixels on each scroll. Ignored that!